# How to solve the problem “Error in scale.default(newdata, object$center, object$scale)“ when do RasterPCA in R

Tags: r, raster

I have four raster data and resample them into the same extent and resoultion, and I need do PCA for them usign rasterPCA package. However I met the error:
Error in scale.default(newdata, object$center, object$scale) :
length of 'center' must equal the number of columns of 'x'

````
library(terra)
library(rasterPCA)

tif <- list.files(path = "F:/data", 
                  pattern = "*.tif", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)

GDP <- rast(tif[1])
AP <- rast(tif[1]) %>% resample(., GDP, method = 'near')
MA <- rast(tif[3]) %>% resample(., GDP, method = 'near')
TP <- rast(tif[4]) %>% resample(., GDP, method = 'near')
Vul <- c(AP,TP,GDP,MA)
Vul_PCA = rasterPCA(Vul, spca = T) ```
````